# Export multiple rows to multiple txt files based on 2 criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, row, criteria, txt

I have a data set with multiple columns and rows (including text, numbers, dates etc). I want the following to happen:

1. Create a txt file for each row.
2. If a Column 1 has duplicate values, create one txt file for all rows with that value.
3. Check Column 2, create files based on column 2 joining onto column 1
4. Date format should be in DD/MM/YYYY
5. Exclude the first two columns
6. Don't need headings
7. The files created are named with Column 1 and 2 content

Example as below. Below is raw information table.

[Raw Information Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Mx2.png)

The query will create 8 Files, one for each employee.

- ABC will have 2 files with only one row in each file because his Department is different
- Benjamin will have 1 file named Benjamin Finance
- Timothy will have one file with BOTH rows named Timothy Marketing
- Charlene will have 1 file
- Tommy will have 1 file
- Jerry will have 1 file
- Lucy will have 1 file with BOTH rows

  ```
  function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet     name.
  var \[, ...values\] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Create an array.
  var csvBalanceArray = [, ...values.reduce((m, r) => m.set(r[0], m.has(r[0]) ? [...m.get(r[0]), r] :     [r]), new Map()).values()];

  // Create text files.
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('###'); // Please set your folder ID.
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  csvBalanceArray.forEach((row, index) => folder.createFile("row" + index + ".txt", row.map(r =>     r.join(" ")).join("\n")));
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var csvBalanceArray = [, ...values.reduce((m, r) => m.set(r[0], m.has(r[0]) ? [...m.get(r[0]), r] :     [r]), new Map()).values()];
```

#### To:

```
var csvBalanceArray = [...values.reduce((m, [h1, h2, ...r]) => {
  var h = h1 + h2;
  var temp = r.map(e => e instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(e, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy") : e);
  return m.set(h, m.has(h) ? [...m.get(h), temp] : [temp]);
}, new Map()).values()];
```

- When this modified script is used, the 1st 2 columns are removed. And, the date object is converted to `dd/MM/yyyy`. And, in this case, the header row is not included.
- From your reply of `however, ABC should have 2 files created because although in Column 1 he is included twice, but in column 2 he is in Finance in row 1 and in Marketing in last row. So he should have two files.`, I updated the above script.

### Added:

About your following new question,

> I've updated the question to add one small change. When the files are created, can these be named as per Column 1 and 2? For example if a file is created for Benjamin, it should be named Benjamin Finance (and so on for other data sets).

and

> So currently, if I run the code, the files created are named row0.txt or row1.txt etc. I would like my files to be named as per Column 1 and 2. For example, the file created for first line in the data table will be named 8124 ABC Finance.txt rather than row0.txt. Similarly, for Timothy, it will be named 8124 TIMOTHY Marketing.txt instead of row3.txt.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet34"); // Please set your sheet name.
  var [, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Create an array.
  var csvBalanceArray = [...values.reduce((m, [h1, h2, ...r]) => {
    var h = h1 + h2;
    var temp = r.map(e => e instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(e, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy") : e);
    var name = `${h1} ${h2}`;
    return m.set(h, m.has(h) ? { row: [...m.get(h).row, temp], name } : { row: [temp], name });
  }, new Map()).values()];
  console.log(csvBalanceArray)

  // Create text files.
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1sJ9b5arpCX26yVIuOKqaen8Mng8KJOiz'); // Please set your folder ID.
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  csvBalanceArray.forEach(({ row, name }) => folder.createFile(`${name}.txt`, row.map(r => r.join(" ")).join("\n")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tanike, however, ABC should have 2 files created because although in Column 1 he is included twice, but in column 2 he is in Finance in row 1 and in Marketing in last row. So he should have two files. The query ran fine for others though. Looking forward to your assistance.

Comment: @saashe Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your actual goal, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, appreciate your help. I've updated the question to add one small change. When the files are created, can these be named as per Column 1 and 2? For example if a file is created for Benjamin, it should be named Benjamin Finance (and so on for other data sets). Appreciate your help to finalise my question. 

Also, can you please explain how is the 'create an array' part working? I'd like some understanding. Thanks

Comment: @saashe Thank you for replying. About `I've updated the question to add one small change.`, I think that it is a new question. Before I think of your new question, I would like to confirm whether your question was resolved by my updated answer. Can I ask you about it? I would like to recommend resolving your question in order. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: thanks. I've accepted your answer. Can you please help me out? Cheers

Comment: @saashe Thank you for replying. I'm glad your initial question was resolved. About your new question and `Can you please help me out?`, I would like to support you. So, about your new question, can I ask you about the detail of it? Because I cannot understand your new question. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. By correctly understanding your new question, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I'm trying to correctly understand your new question.

Comment: No apologies needed @Tanaike. I appreciate your help. So currently, if I run the code, the files created are named row0.txt or row1.txt etc. I would like my files to be named as per Column 1 and 2. For example, the file created for first line in the data table will be named 8124 ABC Finance.txt rather than row0.txt. Similarly, for Timothy, it will be named 8124 TIMOTHY Marketing.txt instead of row3.txt. Please advise if you can adjust the code to include the above? Thanks

Comment: @saashe Thank you for replying. About your new question, I added the sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can confirm it is working now.